# Toggle animate links

Tags: jquery, toggle, hyperlink

I want to toggle the width of links in the following code. Its working but I want the width to revert when I click the another link thereby remaining with one extended link, I hope I make sense.

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">         
    $(document).ready(function () {

    //animate links
    $(".nav_links li a.link").toggle(function(){
        $(this).animate({width:237},200);
    },function(){
        $(this).animate({width:72},200);
    });



    });
</script>
</head>

<body>
<ul>
        <li><a href="#" class="about link"></a></li>
many other links here
        </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use toggle for this, because it's good for one thing - toggle on/off of a singly selected item/group.  What you're trying to do is reset other items while switching on one.  Try something like this instead:

```
$(".nav_links li a.link").click(function(){
    // Reset all links.
    $(".nav_links li a.link").animate({width:72},200);

    // Set currently clicked on as necessary.
    $(this).animate({width:237},200);
});
```

Comment: Kon! May you live forever! You have just saved a soul!